# running current program from vim and viewing output inside vim

Tags: vim, terminal

I want to run my current **Vim** program (**Shell script** in this case) and get output in the same window. I know some **plugins** available or use
**`read` to new buffer**

but this what I am doing .

- Open my program in Vim `vim myshell.sh`
- Split window to new file `:split output`
- `:Set Autoread`
- output the terminal string to that file `:! ./myshell.sh > output`

but i still have double enter to exit from terminal. Any way to by pass this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `silent` for this purpose. But after that you'll need to redraw the window.

So,
`:! ./myshell.sh > output`

And then,
`:redraw!`

You can create a command in your `vimrc` like following:

```
command! -nargs=+ Silent
\ | execute ':silent !' .<q-args>
\ | execute ':redraw!'
```

Then call it like any other command,

`:Silent ./myshell.sh > output`

Comment: You can chain commands, including the 'silent' operator..  `:w|silent! !./% > output`  works in my testing.  `:w` to write the file, `|` to chain commands, `silent!` to run the next command silently, then `!./% > output` which runs the command (% = filename in buffer).